# How do I extract url of a request that failed in Moya

Tags: ios, moya

```
    provider.request(.getRoot) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            print ("root \(response)")
            //            let response = try? response.mapObject(FolderResponse.self)
        //            print ("root \(response) \(response)")
        case .failure(let error):
            let r = result.0.request how do I get the request url from this context???
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            print("BaseURL: \(r)" + (error.errorDescription ?? "Unknown error"))
        }
    }
```

and where does mapObject come from. I got to map the response into a struct (can make that struct Codable if need be)

Answer (score 2):

The response of moya is    `Result<Moya.Response, MoyaError>`

at `failure` you have  `MoyaError`  object which is `Enum`  you can just use `switch - case` to have all error options

```
// A type representing possible errors Moya can throw.

public enum MoyaError: Swift.Error {

    /// Indicates a response failed to map to an image.
    case imageMapping(Response)

    /// Indicates a response failed to map to a JSON structure.
    case jsonMapping(Response)

    /// Indicates a response failed to map to a String.
    case stringMapping(Response)

    /// Indicates a response failed to map to a Decodable object.
    case objectMapping(Swift.Error, Response)

    /// Indicates that Encodable couldn't be encoded into Data
    case encodableMapping(Swift.Error)

    /// Indicates a response failed with an invalid HTTP status code.
    case statusCode(Response)

    /// Indicates a response failed due to an underlying `Error`.
    case underlying(Swift.Error, Response?)

    /// Indicates that an `Endpoint` failed to map to a `URLRequest`.
    case requestMapping(String)

    /// Indicates that an `Endpoint` failed to encode the parameters for the `URLRequest`.
    case parameterEncoding(Swift.Error)
}
```

So you can just can handle moya error like that

```
provider.request(.getRoot) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        print ("root \(response)")
        //            let response = try? response.mapObject(FolderResponse.self)
    //            print ("root \(response) \(response)")
    case .failure(let error):
       self.handleMoyaError(error)
    }
}



//  here you canc heck all of this error
private func handleMoyaError(_ moyaError : MoyaError){

    switch moyaError {
    case let .statusCode(response):
        print(response.request?.url)
    case  .underlying(let nsError as NSError, let response): break
        // nsError  have URL  timeOut , no connection and cancel request
        //  just use response to map  of there is error
    default: break

    }
}
```

Comment: I somehow end in .success on 404 from server. Moya bug?

Comment: Not moya bug  just at ```TargetType```  there is ```validationType```  default value is ```none``` just make it successcode

Comment: var validationType: ValidationType { get }